I try to go to the builder site odoo 16 community and it freezes
I try to go to the builder site and it freezes. This is my odoo.inf configuration. I have ngnix installed:

upstream backend {
 server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}

server {
 listen 80;
 location / {
 proxy_pass http://backend;
 }
 # log files
 access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
 error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

 # Cache static files
 location ~* /web/static/ {
 proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
 proxy_buffering on;
 expires 864000;
 proxy_pass http://backend;
 }

 # Gzip
 gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
 gzip on;

}


When I access the builder's link it redirects me to this site
http://backend/web#action=website.website_preview&path=%2F&website_id=3
and it hangs
When I access the builder's link it redirects me to this site
http://backend/web#action=website.website_preview&path=%2F&website_id=3

You only need to add one line to the server block of your nginx config file. The reason it hangs is that a request is sent via http rather than https.
add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests'; 

